# numpy returning record in a where query for an already deleted index in pandas df

Tags: numpy, pandas

I am trying to run this command:

```
ipums = ipums.drop(np.where(ipums['wkswork1'] == 0)[0])
```

but I am getting an error:

```
raise ValueError('labels %s not contained in axis' % labels[mask])
```

I check the ipums dataset for a value returned in the array:

```
ipums[207]
```

and I get:

```
  File "index.pyx", line 128, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3542)
  File "index.pyx", line 138, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3322)
  KeyError: 207
```

Which I assume it means it was deleted in an earlier record. (And it was because of a similar earlier command that addressed a different field)

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way you would do this in pandas is to use a boolean mask:

```
ipums = ipums[ipums['wkswork1'] != 0]
```

*You can also use a `~` to negate the mask.*

There error is raised because when you use numpy's where it returns the *integer locations* of the rows, rather than the *labels*, this means you can't use [drop](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) (as this uses labels).